# Mass to Light Ratios

Tags: mass, astrophysics, resource-recommendations, data, galaxy-clusters

I know that the mass to light ratio for galaxies is between 2 and 10.  I also know that the ratio changes primarily based on what kind of galaxy you have (elliptical, spiral, etc).  Is there a table somewhere where I can build a relation between the galaxy type and the approximate mass to light ratio?  Could this relationship be used to build a proxy for the baryonic mass of a galaxy cluster?

Comment: Most of the mass in a cluster is not in galaxies, but in the hot gas between the galaxies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a link to a [table of galaxies](http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Faber/Faber3_1.html) which includes distance from Earth, light brightness, radius, rotation velocity, mass, and mass-to-light ratio. For explanation, click "next" at bottom or top of the page. And here is a [portal to a list of galaxy types](https://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Faber/frames.html) and methods of computation.  As you can read in the introduction, various assumptions are made and not all mass is visible.